# no sound available

Tags: sound, 22.04, soundcard

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11 and there is not sound output. On Windows everything is working fine, but on Ubuntu there is not.
I am attaching system information in the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I also tried tuning AlsaMixer, but nothing seems to work.
[image]

Comment: try unmute master or spkr with alsamixer command

Comment: It is again not working. I edited the post and added another screenshot.